# How to make Flexbox (flex-grow) take content into account for sizing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can we get Flexbox to stop equalizing space in sibling elements when both of the elements are using `flex-grow: 1`. This is difficult to explain upfront, so here is the code quickly followed by example screenshots of the issue, and desired behavior.

```css
.Parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.Parent>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="child1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sagittis lorem at odio euismod tincidunt. Proin aliquet velit nec augue venenatis laoreet. Etiam nec metus mi. Aliquam sit amet velit non lectus porttitor accumsan sit amet egestas risus.</div>
  <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

## The issue:

Notice the equal space under the content of each div.
[image]

## Desired:

When there is little content in the children divs, the divs should be of equal height:
[image]

When one of the divs has a lot of content, I would expect the div with more content to only be as tall as the content (if it passes the original flex grow allotment).
[image]

How can I get this behavior? Seems it should be easy using Flexbox.

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpzqMO

Comment: You cannot get the browser to ever *stop* equalizing the free space in flex items with just `flex-grow: 1`/`flex: 1`, because equalizing the free space is *exactly what* `flex-grow: 1` *does*.

Comment: @MichaelCoker You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, yes, just like that. Oh man... I can't tell you how long I've smashed my face against the desk trying to solve this. You should add as an answer!

Comment: @KevBot Cool! Will do, wasn't sure if that's what you were going for :)

Comment: @TylerH, you're right that `flex-grow: 1` by itself won't work, because it leaves untouched the default `flex-basis: auto`. *However*, `flex: 1` should do the trick, because it is supposed to resolve to `flex: 1 1 0`  ([per the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common))...

Comment: ... except, Chrome adds a % unit to the `flex-basis: 0`, which messes up the calculation and kills the layout. If the 0 were left unitless, as it should be, the layout would work with `flex: 1`.

Comment: @Michael_B Oops, I was mixing up the order of `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` in my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flex-basis` is the property you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

> The flex-basis CSS property specifies the flex basis which is the initial main size of a flex item. This property determines the size of the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.

By default, flex will take into account the content in the element when computing `flex-grow` - to disable that, just specify `flex-basis: 0`

```css
.Parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.Parent>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="child1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sagittis lorem at odio euismod tincidunt. Proin aliquet velit nec augue venenatis laoreet. Etiam nec metus mi. Aliquam sit amet velit non lectus porttitor accumsan sit amet egestas risus. Etiam nec metus mi. Aliquam sit amet velit non lectus porttitor accumsan sit amet egestas risus </div>
  <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `min-height` on `.Parent` (along with setting the `flex-direction` to `column`), you're triggering the browser to fill the space with direct descendants of `.Parent`. It does so by distributing the space amongst all elements equally (that's the feature of Flexbox).

If you don't want that behavior, remove the `min-height` from `.Parent` and set a `min-height` on `.Parent > div` elements.

```css
.Parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 400px;
}

.Parent>div {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.Parent > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.Parent > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="child1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sagittis lorem at odio euismod tincidunt. Proin aliquet velit nec augue venenatis laoreet. Etiam nec metus mi. Aliquam sit amet velit non lectus porttitor accumsan sit amet egestas risus. Nullam sagittis lorem at odio euismod tincidunt. Proin aliquet velit nec augue venenatis laoreet. Etiam nec metus mi. Aliquam sit amet velit non lectus porttitor accumsan sit amet egestas risus.</div>
  <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet</div>
  <div>When there is little content in the children divs, the divs should be of equal height.</div>
</div>
```