# Why is a flex container not growing based on a nested flex container child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I have multiple nested flexbox items, I cannot get the parent element to honor the actual height of its children. Here is what I mean:

## Issue:

[image]

## Desired:

When there is content in these cells, it should squish the rows that do not have content until the minimum height is reached of the parent element. After that, it should grow past the minimum height:

[image]

When there is little content in the cells, the rows should take up an even amount of space up until the minimum height (this is already working):

[image]

## My Markup:

```css
.weeks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.week {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.days {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.day {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="weeks">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum consequatur beatae animi porro cumque, tempora delectus voluptates repellat vitae.
      </div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum consequatur beatae animi porro cumque, tempora delectus voluptates repellat vitae.
      </div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can I solve this using flexbox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the `flex-basis` property to `0` on `.week`. Leave it unset and the issue goes away. If you want the `.week` element to have a minimum height, set that property on the `.week` selector.

```css
.weeks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.week {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.days {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.day {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="weeks">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum consequatur beatae animi porro cumque, tempora delectus voluptates repellat vitae.
      </div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="days">
      <div class="day">1</div>
      <div class="day">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum consequatur beatae animi porro cumque, tempora delectus voluptates repellat vitae.
      </div>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, this does work, but I have it set to avoid equal spacing added to each row's content when the content is a little shorter. I needed to ask another question about this issue earlier today ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985719/how-to-make-flexbox-flex-grow-take-content-into-account-for-sizing)). Any ideas on keeping that extra space out of there?